# Whats the difference between getBytes("UTF-8"), getBytes("windows-1252") and getBytes()?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, bytestream

I have following code which produces confusing output..

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

    public class Main {

        String testString = "Moage test String";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Main();
        }

        public Main(){

            System.out.println("Default charset: "+Charset.defaultCharset());
            System.out.println("Teststring: "+testString);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("get the byteStreeam of the test String...");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Bytestream with default encoding: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < testString.getBytes().length; i++){
                System.out.print(testString.getBytes()[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Bytestream with encoding UTF-8: ");
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < testString.getBytes("UTF-8").length; i++){
                    System.out.print(testString.getBytes("UTF-8")[i]);
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Bytestream with encoding windows-1252 (default): ");

                for(int i = 0; i < testString.getBytes("windows-1252").length; i++){
                    System.out.print(testString.getBytes("windows-1252")[i]);
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Bytestream with encoding UTF-16: ");

                for(int i = 0; i < testString.getBytes("UTF-16").length; i++){
                    System.out.print(testString.getBytes("UTF-16")[i]);
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So I wanted to see the difference between utf-8 encoding and windows-1252. 
But when I look at the output, it seems like there is no difference. Only when I cdompare windows-1252 with utf-16 there is a difference.

***Output:***

```
> Default charset: windows-1252 Teststring: Moage test String
> 
> get the byteStreeam of the test String...
> 
> Bytestream with default encoding: 
> 7711197103101321161011151163283116114105110103
> 
> Bytestream with encoding UTF-8: 
> 7711197103101321161011151163283116114105110103
> 
> Bytestream with encoding windows-1252 (default): 
> 7711197103101321161011151163283116114105110103
> 
> Bytestream with encoding UTF-16: 
> -2-1077011109701030101032011601010115011603208301160114010501100103
```

Can anyone explain me why **utf-8 and windows-1252 looks the same**?

Cheers
Alex

Comment: Put some special characters into your test string. Your current test data does not cover the differences between the charsets.

Comment: uaaa thank you!!
I never thought that this would change something. :)

Now there are some differences.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you only use `ASCII` characters in your test `String` which is in your case `"Moage test String"`, try with special characters such as `"éèà"` for example, you will then see different results.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

You used the String Characters of which belongs to the Range of `ASCII`. If your string contains any **special Character** or **language which supports Special Character** You Bytes Output will be changed.

> UTF-8 is generally approved standard, which works everywhere. But , Windows-any encoding is Windows-specific and not guaranteed to work on any machine.